# "Circular redirect path detected" when sharing a Wordpress post on facebook

Tags: wordpress, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I have a travel blog running on a server in goDaddy (unfortunatelly I already paid a 2 years packet). My knowledge about web apps is minimal, so I even pay for the Wordpress service, so in theory my only work would be to write the posts.
I have the official facebook plugin, the jetpack and the OpenGraph plugins installed.
Recently (after the latest update I think) I started having problems when sharing on facebook. The image doesn't appear, and the link is to the home of my page, and not to the post. 
I can solve the problem by enabling/disabling the plugins after each post, but this is obviously not a good solution.
After reading some people with a similar problem, I found about the facebook debuger. So I run there and I get this error:

```
Circular Redirect Path
Circular redirect path detected (see 'Redirect Path' section for details).
.
Extraneous Property
Objects of this type do not allow properties named 'twitter:card'.
.
Extraneous Property
Objects of this type do not allow properties named 'article:section'.
.
Extraneous Property
Objects of this type do not allow properties named 'article:published_time'.
.
Extraneous Property
Objects of this type do not allow properties named 'article:modified_time'.
.
Extraneous Property
Objects of this type do not allow properties named 'article:author'.
.
Extraneous Property
Objects of this type do not allow properties named 'article:tag'.
.
Parser Mismatched Metadata
The parser's result for this metadata did not match the input metadata.     Likely, this was caused by the data being ordered in an unexpected way, multiple values being given for a property only expecting a single value, or property values for a given property being mismatched. Here are the input properties that were not seen in the parsed result: 'og:title, og:type, og:image:url, og:description, og:locale:locale, og:site_name, twitter:card, article:section, article:published_time, article:modified_time, article:author, fb:app_id, og:image:width, og:image:height, article:tag'
```

Anyone knows a solution for this? I read something about updating the "meta properties", but I have no idea where to find it.

My blog is http://www.mundosemfim.com, and here is the result of a scan in my latest post:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=http%3A%2F%2Fmundosemfim.com%2Ftop-15-america-do-sul-destinos-imperdiveis-no-nosso-continente%2F